# Spring AOP not working

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am trying to create some annotations which check permissions from the securitycontext before accessing some protected resources. I wrote a sample code very similar to what I would want to implement, however when I invoke SomethingProtected(), it seems like the @Before part of the aspect never actually gets triggered. Any help would be appreciated.

I have:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface NeedsPermissions {
    boolean read() default true;
}
```

and

```
@Aspect
public class NeedsPermissionsAspect {
    @Before("execution(* *.*(..)) && @annotation(NeedsPermissions)")
    public void CheckPermissions(JoinPoint pjp, NeedsPermissions needsPermissions) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("aspect");
        if (needsPermissions.read() == true) {
            SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContext.getSecurityContext();
            MyUser user = securityContext.getUser();
            if (!user.read){
                throw new Exception("Not Allowed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class NeedsPermissionsConfig {
}
```

and

```
public class ProtectedResource {

    @NeedsPermissions
    public void SomethingProtected(){
        System.out.println("Something protected");
    }
}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>



    <!-- Aspect -->
    <bean id="needsPermissionsAspect" class="NeedsPermissionsAspect">
        <!-- configure properties of aspect here as normal -->
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Remove `static`. You cannot intercept static methods calls with Spring AOP due the the proxy based nature of it.

Comment: @M.Deinum I removed the static modifier, however the aspect is still not kicking in. Any other ideas?

Comment: It also needs to be a spring bean, spring AOP will only work on spring beans.

Answer (score 3):

try to change you annotation with this

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I can tell you that with Spring 3.X the annotation in the configuration is not necessary.
It's enough to have the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This way you can use the AspectJ annotations:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
```

You need to annotate the class with both @Aspect and @Component.+

Also make sure that your Pointcut is aiming at the right position in the package, otherwise you won't see anything in the logs, as the pointcut won't find the methods.
For example, it the method is found under "com.demo.messaging.MyClass.myMethod" you need something like

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.demo.messaging.*.*(..))")
```